# Как обычно называют классы-контейнеры, хранящие набор параметров для создания экземпляров других классов?

Tags: ооп, проектирование

Есть класс-контейнер орм, который хранит какой-то набор данных в своих экземплярах.

Например:

```
class КлассКонтейнер(ОрмКласс):
    название: str
    сила: int
    здоровье: int

class Существо(ОрмКласс):
    исходник: КлассКонтейнер
    текущее_здоровье: int

ещё_не_гоблин = КлассКонтейнер(название="Гоблин", сила=5, здоровье=5)
гоблин = Существо(исходник=ещё_не_гоблин)
гоблин_2 = Существо(исходник=ещё_не_гоблин)
```

Как обычно назвают такие классы? Как я понимаю, это не префаб. Префабом можно было бы сделать любого гоблина.

Comment: А какая ответсвенности у класса контейнера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне хорошо помогает размышления вида - а что тут сущность и как соотносятся разные сущности?

У вас есть явная сущность "Существо". У неё есть некие характеристики (имя(?), сила, здоровье etc). Если характеристики типовые (т.е. наборы характеристик вида гоблин-главный гоблин-гоблин шаман), то я бы назвал это "Шаблоном", особенно с учетом того, что вы из него и создаете своих гоблинов. Но, это сугубо техническая часть ваших характеристик и некоторые такое не любят =)

Поэтому есть второй вариант - назвать это просто характеристиками\статами персонажа. Тогда это более "предметный" термин и он сразу становится понятнее для стороннего человека. Однако, имя сюда уже не вписывается. Имя, очевидно, не имеет отношения к характеристикам.

Для выбора из этих двух вариантов мне лично пришлось бы решить вопрос - могу я создать крысу с характеристиками гоблина или они уникальны? Если могу - то победил второй вариант, если не могу - то скорее первый.

ПС: и да, я предпочитаю использовать DDD при продумывании сущностей, хотя тут нужен опыт, прямо так сразу ничего хорошего придумать не получается, нужно сидеть и рисовать схемы, хоть на листочке, хоть в каком-нибудь UML редакторе.

ПС2: понятия не имею, что такое префаб. Судя по гуглу, это такое слово мусорка - нам надо сохранить что-то и мы назовём хранилище чего-угодно - префабом.

Comment: Префаб - это префабричный экземпляр.